# How can I write a query with searching of full name?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, oracle, eloquent

I have a problem with the query which will search users by full name.

But when I typed

```
$user = Polzovatel::select()
    ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(fam, ' ',imya)"), 'like', '%'. $request->input('polnoe_imya').'%')
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(fam, ' ',imya)"), 'like', '%'. $request->input('fullName').'%')
    ->get();
```

that return data of user only when request is equivalent to 'Tom Walke' or 'Walker To' but when my search request will be like 'To Wal' it just return empty array. So what can I do with this problem? Name and surname are in different column. But query with concatenate it is not quite correct

Comment: You can use Full Text Searching with wildcard `*` at the end of each word in the input string. Define a composite Full Text Index on `(name, surname)`

Comment: you can split the fullname based on space and they search for each part of fullname separately against surname, name

Comment: @Aleks Isn't that what the documentation is for?

Comment: @Aleks please Google Full Text Searching MySQL tutorial; there is enormous content available on this. Try something based on that, and when you are stuck, you can edit the question with your latest efforts, and then we can improvize on it. `Like %%` cannot use index and hence will be inefficient on big tables. FTS is the way to go; so it would be better if you read some basics about it.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya oh, thank you for this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `%` around each word in the name, not just the whole name. So if the inpupt is `To Wai`, your pattern will be `%To% %Wai%`.

```
$pattern = implode(' ', 
    array_map(function($word) { return "%$word%"; },
              explode(' ', $request->input('fullName'))));
$user = UserData::select()
    ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(surname, ' ',name)"), 'like', $pattern)
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(name, ' ',surname)"), 'like', $pattern)
    ->get();
```